# how to setting up webpack to angular2 project

Tags: angular, webpack

I am starting my first Angular 2 application and my basic setup is done. I want to know that how can I webpack to my angular 2 project? can anyone guide me here? If you can provide an example then it would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Angular CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to create your project, that means you are set up everything with Webpack including unit test, end to end test and Webpack test server etc.

Angular CLI is official and recommended for almost all Angular 2 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html
There's step by step guide how to configurate webpack for angulr2